# Turning a constrained optimal control problem into unconstrained (Lagrangian)

Tags: optimization, lagrange-multiplier, control-theory, optimal-control, functional-calculus

If I wish to minimize the cost function
$$
J(x(\cdot),u(\cdot)) = \int_0^TL(x,u)dt
$$

with dynamics constraint $\dot{x}(t) = f(x(t),u(t))$ $\forall t$, many textbooks state that this constrained optimization problem can be reformulated as an unconstrained optimization problem:

$$
\tilde{J}(x(\cdot),u(\cdot),\lambda(\cdot)) = J(x(\cdot),u(\cdot)) + \int_0^T\lambda^T(t)(\dot{x}(t) - f(x(t),u(t)))dt
$$

I can't quite see how this captures the constraint... Isn't it possible that the integral could be zero without the constraint *actually* being satisfied?

(for example, if $(\dot{x}(t) - f(x(t),u(t)) = 1$ from $t = [0,0.5T]$ and $-1$ from $t = [0.5T,T]$)

How does this form imply that the constraint is satisfied if we minimize this unconstrained cost $\tilde{J}$ over $\lambda$?

__

Edit: I know that in a standard Lagrangian optimization problem, if we take the derivative w.r.t. $\lambda$, that we recover the original equality constraint. In this case since $\lambda(t)$ is a function, I need to do something related to functional derivatives rather than a normal derivative. However, I am not sure where to begin with this.

Comment: You are not looking for the integral to be zero but for the constraint to be zero at all times.

Comment: I know, what I'm trying to figure out is how this unconstrained optimization problem actually achieves that the constraint is zero. To me, it looks like it is saying that the integral is zero, which I understand is not correct. I don't know how to show this, my knowledge of functionals is very shaky.

Comment: In fact, you are asking why Euler-Lagrange Method for dynamic optimization (and in part also why Hamiltons Method, since they are equivalent using the Legendre transformation) provide the correct solution. There are many proofs in the textbooks, see e.g. Optimal Control from D. Kirk.

Comment: Thank you for the tip - dynamic optimization and Euler-Lagrange method gives me a great place to start. I had no idea what to even call this type of problem, and so was really struggling to find what I was looking for. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @bsprenger glad to help :) In dynamic optimization you search for an optimal function minimizing the objective function (i.e. you search in a infinite dimensional space, since a function space is infinitely many basis functions). In parameter optimization (the most common optimization) you search for a scalar or vector (i.e. you search in a finite dimentional space, i.e. $\mathbb{R}^n$ for $n in \mathbb{R}$) minimizing your optimization problem.